# POST request using python-maas-client

Tags: python, maas

How can we do the post request to maas api using the python-maas-client.

I am getting the details from maas api using the maas-client by the following code.

```
print maas_access.get(u"networks").read()
print maas_access.get(u"users").read()
```

But when i try to post a request I am getting the error. code is below

```
data = {'username':'murali','email':'muralidharan.s@poornam.com','password':'murali','is_superuser': 0}
maas_access.post(u"users/", "new", data)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "api.py", line 48, in <module>
    maas_access.post(u"users/", "new", data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apiclient/maas_client.py", line 250, in post
    url, method="POST", headers=headers, data=body)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apiclient/maas_client.py", line 116, in dispatch_query
    res = urllib2.urlopen(req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 127, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 410, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 523, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 448, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 531, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: BAD REQUEST
```

and if i Use

```
 data = {'username':'murali','email':'muralidharan.s@poornam.com','password':'murali','is_superuser': 0}
maas_access.post(u"users/", data)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "api.py", line 49, in <module>
    maas_access.post(u"users/", data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apiclient/maas_client.py", line 248, in post
    path, kwargs, as_json=as_json)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apiclient/maas_client.py", line 218, in _formulate_change
    url += '?' + urlencode([('op', op)])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apiclient/utils.py", line 48, in urlencode
    for name, value in data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apiclient/utils.py", line 48, in <genexpr>
    for name, value in data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apiclient/utils.py", line 45, in <lambda>
    string.encode("utf-8") if isinstance(string, unicode) else string)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 1295, in quote_plus
    return quote(s, safe)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 1286, in quote
    if not s.rstrip(safe):
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'rstrip'
```

Is I am missing some thing or the data that i providing is wrong ?
Please help me

Answer (score 0):

While there is no actual documentation for the current form of the apiclient, reading the source for the signature of the post() method:

```
def post(self, path, op, as_json=False, **kwargs):
    """Dispatch POST method `op` on `path`, with the given parameters.

    :param as_json: Instead of POSTing the content as multipart/form-data
        POST it as application/json
    :return: The result of the dispatch_query call on the dispatcher.
    """
```

That suggests that any data you provide needs to be submitted as kwargs; as below:

```
maas_access.post(u"users/", "new", **data)
```

There is one more problem with your data, though, which is that you are submitting an integer as an argument; instead, submit it as the string '0':

```
data = {'username':'murali', 'email':'muralidharan.s@poornam.com', 
     'password':'murali', 'is_superuser': '0'}
maas_access.post(u"users/", "new", **data)
```

Finally, note that that API is insecure as it supplies the password as plaintext, as indicated in the [API documentation](https://maas.ubuntu.com/docs/api.html#users).

See http://blog.allenap.me/2013/06/workaround-for-uploading-files-to-maas.html for a more complete example of using the client's post() API.

Comment: Hi kiko  thanks  for the reply.  We are getting another error now . http://paste.ubuntu.com/12514596/

Comment: I have tried with the following 
data =
{'username':names, 'email':emailss, 'password':passwds, 'is_superuser': sup}

maas_access.post(u"users/", "create", **data)
maas_access.post(u"users/", "POST", **data)
maas_access.post(u"users/", "None", **data)
maas_access.post(u"users/", "new", **data)
maas_access.post(u"users/", "add", **data)

Getting the following error
raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: BAD REQUEST

Answer (score 0):

```
sshKeys = {"key": [keyValue]}
maas_access.post(u"account/prefs/sshkeys/", "new", **sshKeys)
```

The above code will post the ssh key into the maas using maas-api. But in case of user it is not working. Still getting 400 error